# 'Shift' + 'enter' only works when the text line is highlighted. How do I change it, so I don't have to highlight?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, highlight, enter, python-3.7

I'm new in Spyder and Python and hope that someone could help me with a very fundamental question.
I succeed in running a cell (cmd + enter) or running a cell and advance (shift + enter), but only when the textline is **HIGHLIGTHED**.

How do I change it, so I **don't have to highlight every time**?

e.g.: a = 3
First I have to highlight and then cmd + enter before the variable is defined.

I use Python 3.7 and Spyder 3.2.2

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Simply create cells by using comments of the form `#%%` and then press `{Ctrl, Shift} + Enter` inside the regions delimited by those comments.

Comment: Thank you. It helps with 'shift'+'enter'. But with 'cmd'+'enter' it doesn't advance...
And it makes the background orange.
But it works better.

Comment: `Cmd+Enter` is not meant to advance but to stay on the current cell.